# Why does mysql give me error 1136 everytime I try to upload my database?

Tags: mysql

I try to upload the database to MYSQL and this is the error that I'm getting: 1136 column count doesnt match value count at row 1

*INSERT INTO accounts (pID, Name, pKey, pLevel, pForma, pAdmin, pPasport, pTime, pYears, pHelper, pJobHeal, pJobHealLeader, pMestoJail, pIp, pvIp, pIpReg, pHousecash, pCheckip, pText, pKeyip, pHP, pSatiety, pDataReg, pCar, pFuelcar, pProcents, pDonateRank, pDonatemoney, pReg, pMats, pSex, pArrested, pMuted, pCrimes, pExp, pCash, pKills, pDeaths, pWantedDeaths, pPayCheck, pJailed, pCheat, pJailTime, pDrugs, pLeader, pMember, pRank, pChar, pJob, pZadanie, pHealth, pSHealth, pInt, pLocal, pModel, pPnumber, pPhoneBook, pDirectory, pVhoddata, pVhodMes, pVhodchas, pVhodminute, pCarLic, pFlyLic, pBoatLic, pFishLic, pGunLic, pBizLic, pNkeys, pPhousekey, pPbiskey, pAvtomas, pZakonp, pAddiction, pNarcoLomka, pPayDay, pPayDayHad, pTut, pVig, pWarns, punWarns, punWarnstime, pFuel, pMarried, pMarriedTo, pDrug, pFishes, pDrugmoney, pMuteTime, pBank, pBanDay, pBanMounth, pKazpay,  pMobile, pDostup, pLocked, , pKrisha,  pWantedLevel,  pGunSkill1, pGunSkill2, pGunSkill3, pGunSkill4, pGunSkill5, pGunSkill6, ptaxiexp, ptaxilvl,  pGunfbiTime, pGun51Time, pGunlspdTime, pGunaviaTime, pDrugtime, pBoxstyle, pKstyle, pKickstyle, pBoxSkill, pKongfuSkill, pKickboxSkill, pWheels, pPaintJob, pSpoiler, pBumper1, pBumper2, pColor1, pColor2, pNitro, pHydrawlic, pBulletSP, pOnline, pChar1, pChar2, pViborChar, pChas, pMin, pEmail, pOnlineLid, pLogin, pKvartiraKey, pKazino, pKRank, pSkilla, pLighter, pCigarettes, pRecognition,  Online_status, pQira, pNeon, pVipTime, pProcents1, pWheels1, pPaintJob1, pSpoiler1, pBumper11, pBumper21, pNeon1, pColor11, pColor21, pNitro1, pHydrawlic1, pFuelcar1, pCar1, pBonus, pCasinop, pFuelcar2, pCar2, pHealme, pProcents2, pWheels2, pPaintJob2, pSpoiler2, pNitro2, pHydrawlic2, pNeon2, pBumper31, pBumper32, pColor31, pColor32, pAccesoire) VALUES*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SfVa.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Because the number of values must match the number of column names. For example:

```
insert into my_table (col1, col2, col3) values (123, 'abc', 456);
```

There are **three** column names and **three** values. If you had a non matching number like two vs three, then it would throw the error you mention.

Your query is quite extensive. You'll need to debug it in detail to find out if you are missing a column name or a value.